# Create rewrite rule Url in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

i have a WordPress site, i created a new template which show some data through query string. 
i want to create a rewrite rule in WordPress to follow this structure.

```
www.example.com/somePage/products/?mfg=UETD342
```

to

```
www.example.com/somePage/products/UETD342/
```

Thanks

Comment: You can look into .htaccess Rewrite mode

Comment: You can also check wordpress function _add_rewrite_rule_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add custom URL tag using below code:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%mfg%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

and add below code to add your own custom rewrite rule for loading your page with this parameter:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
     add_rewrite_rule('^products/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=your_page_id&mfg=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

you need to add both codes in your theme's functions.php

For a more detailed knowledge of url rewriting visit:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Can you please answer this my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544224/wordpress-custom-url-writting-not-working